# Java Jersey How can I block loggingFilter prints?

Tags: java, spring, server, jersey

I'm using `jersey` `loggingFilter` class that print all requests/responses content.
Here is the filter connection code:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.scope.RequestContextFilter;

import com.ladpc.mobile.util.CORSResponseFilter;
import com.ladpc.mobile.util.LoggingResponseFilter;

/**
 * Registers the components to be used by the JAX-RS application
 * 
 * @author ama
 *
 */
public class MobileApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    /**
     * Register JAX-RS application components.
     */
    public MobileApplication() {
        try {
            register(RequestContextFilter.class);
            register(TaskService.class);
            register(LookupService.class);
            register(UsersService.class);
            register(PropertyService.class);
            register(DocumentsPathService.class);
            register(DocumentsService.class);
            register(WorkPlanService.class);
            register(IssueService.class);
            register(ActionTypesService.class);
            register(JacksonFeature.class);
            register(LoggingResponseFilter.class);
            register(MyApplicationEventListener.class);
            registerInstances(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getLogger(MobileApplication.class.getName()), true));
            register(CORSResponseFilter.class);
            register(MultiPartFeature.class);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem: some of responses content is too long because it's contain byte array of image content or pdf files content, so when the client call to this service more than once the log file is fill up and its cause many running problems.
There is a way to block some of services that there response not printed automatically by the loggingFilter class?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out...
In this line:

```
registerInstances(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getLogger(MobileApplication.class.getName()), true));
```

There is c-tor call, the second param is 'boolean printEntity'- true if want to print the response content, false- if not....

so change this line to:

```
 registerInstances(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getLogger(MobileApplication.class.getName()), false));
```

can solve this issue.